# CSS Braces not showing in email source

Tags: html, css, email

I'm trying to send an email with css in the head; however, when I check the source code of the email (once it has been deployed), the braces appear as the paragraph symbol. What could be causing this?

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">body {color:green;background-color:#000;}
</style></head><body>
```

Comment: How are you sending this email?

Comment: How are you viewing the source code? What software do you use? Are you viewing it after you have sent the email? Do you get the same result with different (recipient) mail account providers?

Comment: I'm using a program called Dialogue to enter the HTML, but it goes to our mainframe before being sent (and I'm not sure what happens there). I'm viewing it in Outlook 2007 by right-clicking the email. I haven't been able to test others, but according to my team, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Most web email clients remove embedded stylesheets to prevent them from breaking the client itself. Imagine you were using Gmail and re-defined the mail interface with your stylesheet. You'd could break everything.

Answer (score 0):

Some MS Exchange servers (especially corporate ones with security software) strip or edit the style tags. It could be that is what is messing with your code. Try sending to an account that is not on the same network ie: you@adifferentdomain.com to see if it makes a difference.

As Diodeus mentions, it is best practice to inline your code, that will give you the most consistent results across all major email clients.